# document.ready function is not working inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

In the parent page I have an iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="facts.php" style="width:320px; height:500px; border:hidden" id="facts">  </iframe>
```

And inside of that iframe I have a jQuery function like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo').hide();
    $('.vticker').easyTicker();
});
</script>
```

But this function doesn't trigger when the parent page is loaded. Can you please explain me how to solve this?

Comment: this will be fired when the iframe is loaded, why do you want it to be fired when the parent page is loaded

Comment: Actually it doesn't tiger after the iframe is loaded as well.

Comment: Do the #demo and .vticker elements you are trying to effect exist within the iframe or in the parent? (A script in an iframe can't see elements outside the frame.)

Comment: Those are exist inside of the iframe.

Comment: Are you including your link to jquery in the inner frame?

Comment: Yes, script and the content related to the #demo and .vticker are exists inside the iframe.

Comment: Nothing appears to be wrong from the information you've given. I would try the following to troubleshoot: if you put an alert inside the ready function does it fire? If you put it ouside the ready function (before close script) does it fire? If you place alert($().jquery); before the close script, does it fire? What are the contents that show in the alert? Do you have error messages in your javascript console?

Comment: Not at all constructive, but I'd love a "reday" function, like a sassier jQuery.

Comment: As @BriAnna mentioned, jQuery needs to be loaded inside the iframe also. The iframe never inherits anything from the parent window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this inside your iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo').hide();
    $('.vticker').easyTicker();
});
</script>
```

You are facing this issue because the parent JavaScript cannot access the events inside the iframe. You better include the script inside the source of the iframe.

Comment: Did this really solve the OP's issue?  I similarly have jquery loaded inside the iframe, above the script calling it, and find that the $(document).ready(function() is never called.

Comment: @Ashimema i can confirm, document ready never gets called ;( in my case i have different domains, but jquery gets included inside the iframe, so that´s not a real solution here....

Comment: Same here.  I'm using an iFrame to preview a page in a CMS.  The "real" page works fine and the contents of the iFrame is identical but the call to $(document).ready() never executes.  No errors either.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like cross side scripting to me.
First of all try this in your iframe:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        alert("iFrame is ready");
    });
</script>
```

If this does not work, check if you includet jQuery the right way.

Remember: your iframe is a complete selfstanding webside. There is no communication between your main frame and your iframe.
That means if you use Javascript in your iframe you can only manipulate HTML-code inside the iframe.
If you want to manipulate HTML-elements outside of the iframe you need to include the Javascript in your main frame.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same issue. i was using relative path to add jQuery file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jquery.js"></script>
```

by adding '/' it solved my issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you add forward slash it will take the path from root directory other wise it considers it as relative path. Some how here you root path got matched